# Android setOnItemClickListener with Cardslib

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter. The ArrayAdapter's `getView()` returns a view with a CardListView in it. I'm trying to set an OnItemClickListener for the ListView. It compiles fine but clicking on an item (which is a view of a CardListView) does nothing. Is there a way around this?

Here's my `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    List<String> cardTextGroup = cardTextList.get(position);
    List<Card> cardGroup = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cardTextGroup.size(); i++) {
        Card card = new Card(context);
        MatchOngoing.HeaderInnerCard header = new MatchOngoing.HeaderInnerCard(context);
        String cardText = cardTextGroup.get(i);
        if (!cardText.equals(blackCardText)) {
            header.setCardText(cardText);
            card.addCardHeader(header);
            card.setBackgroundResourceId(R.drawable.card_background);
            cardGroup.add(card);
        }
    }

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        // Create inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Get item view from inflater
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_ongoing_table_item, null);
    }

    CardListView cardGroupView =
            (CardListView) view.findViewById(R.id.match_ongoing_table_played_cards_group);
    CardArrayAdapter cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(context, cardGroup);
    cardGroupView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e6e6e6"));
    cardGroupView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: A CardListView inside a ListView is not a good option.

Comment: it depends by what is your purpose

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at CustomCard.java adapter and you'll understand how to use alternate to onitemclicklistener

where i is the number of card clicked in the listview

```
public class CustomCard extends Card  {
    String[] listData1;
    protected TextView mTitle;
    Intent mainIntent1;
    Context context;
    int i;
    SpannableString s;
    /**
     * Constructor with a custom inner layout
     * @param context
     */
    public CustomCard(Context context,String[] listData1, int i) {
        this(context, R.layout.adapter_text);
        this.context=context;
        this.i=i;
        this.listData1=listData1;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param context
     * @param innerLayout
     */
    public CustomCard(Context context, int innerLayout) {
        super(context, innerLayout);
        init();
    }



    /**
     * Init
     */
    private void init(){

        //No Header

        //Set a OnClickListener listener
        setOnClickListener(new OnCardClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(i==1)
                {
                    mainIntent1 = new Intent(context,WeightBand.class);
                    mainIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(mainIntent1);
                }
                if(i==0)
                {
                    mainIntent1 = new Intent(context,AerobicsSchedule.class);
                    mainIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(mainIntent1);
                }
                if(i==2)
                {
                    mainIntent1= new Intent(context,AdditionalExercises.class);
                    mainIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(mainIntent1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {

        //Retrieve elements


    }
}
```